# filtering out false positives of object detection with opencv

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

im using opencv's HaarDetectObjects(...) to detect an object in an image. The function returns the coordinates of areas in the image that might contain the object, the problem is i only want to detect a single instance of the object in the image and i have no way of knowing which of the results returned by the function is the "best". is there a way i could get the results sorted by their probability of actually containing the object ? or maybe define some sort of threshold the results must pass ? basically, i need a way of filtering out the false positives.

i am not restricted to using opencv or HaarDetectObjects, if anyone has a suggestion for another library or another object detection method, it is welcome.

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any domain specific knowledge you can take advantage of?

If the object is expected to be of a certain size or is most likely to be in certain position, you can define a very simple index that measures how far each detection is from being that size/position, so that would be your probability of a detection actually being the object.

Is it expected to be of certain color? You can take the color histogram of a sample object. Then, you could compare each detection that HaarDetectObjects has returned to this sample histogram using a distance function (for the distance function, the names "Bhattacharyya distance" and "Mahalanobis distance" pop up in my mind, but I can't claim any expertise on this. OpenCv does have [support for histograms](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/histograms.html), though, including a CompareHist function).

Is there anything you can say about the object's contours, texture, geometry...? Anything that can be reduced to numbers and compared to a "ground value" can be of help.

All of this, of course, is subject to processing constraints. Some of these suggestions might or might not be a bit expensive in terms of computation time. And this might or might not affect your application, depending of whether you have hardware or real time constraints.

Comment: i was a little lost at first, but in retrospect - your answer was very helpful. thank you.